# web logic 12CR2, how to get deployed application name in partition level

Tags: web-applications, deployment, weblogic, information-retrieval, partition

I am trying find out a way to get the deployed application name in partition level for a while. But I didn't get any way works! If who is working this way, please advise!

Since Weblogic 12cR2 (12.2.1.0.0), FMW supports multiple tenants stay in single domain in partition level. Which is very good for the one who has to run multiple applications in single Weblogic instance.

If we deploy web app in domain level, we can simply by using WLST to access the deployed application name by:

```
connect('<adminusername>','<adminpassword>','<t3://adminurl>)
domainConfig()
vasApps=cmo.getAppDeployments()
for app in vasApps:
  print app.getName()
```

But unfortunately this function not work any more as newer version deployment will put applications into partition level resource group. The problem raised up as we don't know the app is deployed or not, if you are deployer, want to redeploy it or update application (that already deployed) in need, there is no way to find the existing apps by their name.

If any one have some idea, please share with me!

Comment: I had found out why, as from Weblogic 12cR2, FMW support partition level administrator to manage their own deployed application, so if I connected to Weblogic by using administrator, all the applications were deployed into partition is not visible. I believe it is a bug, as Weblogic documents shows administrator have the right to access every individual partition's apps